# Online events during the quarantine

Tags: reference-request, online-resources, math-communication, conferences

With many places on earth subjected to quarantine and large gathering prohibited, there are announcements of online seminars and talks open to people around the world. The talks can be conducted via ZOOM or other platforms. As far as I know, the information about them is spread by the word of mouth, or more precisely personal emails.

Are there some sources/online pages where information about ongoing online events im mathematics is collected? I am interested in probability in particular, but I assume other people would be interested in events related to their research interests.

A somewhat similar question was asked [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/19174/informal-online-seminars-or-reading-groups-via-videoconferencing) 10 years ago but the circumstances are different now, and the available technological tools are more advanced.

Comment: Aram Dermenjian put together a nice resource for online seminars in algebraic combinatorics speficially: http://dermenjian.com/seminars/

Comment: I think the question should be more clearly either focussed on probability, or not focussed at all.

Comment: This (more recent) question is also related: [Software and ideas for workshops and conferences with long-distance participants](https://mathoverflow.net/q/349283).

Comment: This is a topic of great current interest. But a list of online seminars and talks is certain to be out-of-date very soon. Perhaps MathOverflow is not the right place for this list; but I hope that there is a good place for it somewhere.

Comment: In case you did not have the informations, there is the One World Probability Seminar https://www.wim.uni-mannheim.de/doering/one-world/

Comment: @FrançoisBrunault: And an analogous event for the PDE crowd: https://people.bath.ac.uk/mw2319/owpde/

Comment: I think https://jaume.dedios.cat/math-seminars/ is a very good list.

Answer (score 34):

I invite you to look at [researchseminars.org](https://researchseminars.org).

Anyone can create listings for seminars or conferences, either as an organizer or as a curator. These listings will automatically appear once the individual has been endorsed (similar to arXiv endorsing). The goal is to distribute the task of maintaining up to date listings as broadly as possible.   When browsing talks and seminars, you can filter by topic or institution, tag your favorite talks or seminars, and export to your calendar (new talks in a seminar you have subscribed to will automatically show up in your calendar).  Times are automatically translated to a user's local time zone.

We've added a few seminars that we found online. We are in the process of adding more. If you would like to join our efforts, you're very welcome!

Comment: This is the most accessible webpage I’ve come across so far. Great job.

Answer (score 12):

One ongoing effort to collect online seminars in all areas of mathematics (indicated by arXiv category) is by Ao Sun (MIT) and Mingchen Xia (Chalmers), on [this website](https://math.mit.edu/~aosun/online_seminars.html).

Answer (score 4):

Dan Isaksen put together a [list](https://s.wayne.edu/isaksen/online-mathematics-seminars/) of online seminars and events on his webpage.

Comment: Not just a list of seminars, it's also *a list of lists of seminars*!

Answer (score 4):

Some seminars in Russia which are now online, mentioned here:

http://www.mathnet.ru/php/seminars.phtml?option_lang=rus

For some zoom/skype-id is shown, for other one should probably ask the organizers.

Answer (score 3):

AMS has started a list, organized by mathematical field, at https://www.ams.org/profession/online-talks.

Answer (score 2):

Terrence Tao shares an online website for seminar. Have a look [Here](https://jaume.dedios.cat/math-seminars/)
or [Here](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2020/04/07/mathematics-seminars-list/). I hope i understand the question.